# Unity setting rectTransform on an UI Image with a Vector3, do I need to convert coords?

Tags: unity, ui-design

I am trying to build a menu with a cursor.  I created the menu and that in the unity UICamera on the canvas.  It looks great.  I want the cursor to move so what I did was move the cursor by hand and record the values at each location I want the cursor to possibly be (see attached).  The problem is later when I try to set the value to these via this:

```
pauseCursor.rectTransform.position = new Vector3 (-45f, -80.6f, 0);
```

It fails and looking in the inspector again the x,y values are like 300, 800 or something.  I am guessing I need a conversion I just am not sure where or how.
Do I get the Ui camera reference and use the WorldToScreen?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `localPosition` (the position of the GameObject in relation to its direct parent).  Otherwise it will set the absolute/global position and it will re-calculate the `localPosition` (that's the one that actually shows up in the inspector) and will look wrong.

```
pauseCursor.rectTransform.localPosition = new Vector3 (-45f, -80.6f, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead :

```
pauseCursor.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector3 (-45f, -80.6f, 0);
```

Comment: We generally like more details in an answer, not a lonely block of code.